# R packages not loading after update (Error: package ‘spatstat.data’ could not be loaded)

Tags: r, installation, rtools

I cannot get spatstat to install properly in R.

I have updated R to the newest version(4.1.2) and installed RTools40 following these instructions (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html).

I have restarted R several times and tried to install spatstat as well as spatstat data, but whenever I try and call the library, I get the following error

````
library(spatstat)
Loading required package: spatstat.data
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘spatstat.data’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/stats/libs/i386/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package ‘spatstat.data’ could not be loaded

library(spatstat.data)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘spatstat.data’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/stats/libs/i386/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.```
````

Small update:
I've tried this for other tools as well and I'm getting the same error.
Example:

```
library(GISTools)
Loading required package: maptools
Loading required package: sp
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sp’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/stats/libs/i386/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package ‘sp’ could not be loaded

library(sp)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sp’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/stats/libs/i386/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

Another update: I now get this error when I start R.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is weird with your R installation. Is it an option to remove R, restart and install it again? Do recommend packages even work? E.g. `library(MASS)`?

Comment: So I was having this issue and did exactly that. I uninstalled everything and reinstalled but it's still happening. I'm also now getting an error on startup (see edit)

Comment: It still seems like your R installation is problematic. One of the core parts of R is the stats package, which is part of all R installations and it seems you don't have this core component. I cannot understand why you don't have it if you do a clean reinstall. Do you have another computer where you can try to install R and check that the same problem occurs?

Comment: yes, I have uninstalled everything and reinstalled everything and I'm still getting the same error. I should add that the standard R gui seems to be working, the error seems to occur only in RStudio

Comment: I just unintalled and reinstalled again (this time even downloading new .exe files even though I knew that was unlikely to do anything). I also installed to "C://" instead of "Program Files" but I'm still getting the same error. I'd like to point out that I created an .Renviron file (as per the instructions linked above) and I'm wondering if that could have caused any issues? I'm not even sure why I need to install RTools separately. I have not done this in the past

Comment: Try to remove the created .Renviron file to have a clean install. If the problem only occurs in RStudio you should try to get help related to that. They both have their own forum and a tag here at SO, which I will try to attach to your question instead of spatstat which is unrelated to your problem. I don't think you need Rtools for anything if you are not a developer and need development versions of packages.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to delete the .Renviron file that was created and then everything worked